Flutter builded app (apk) doesn't launch on my mobile phone
When I download the app it just crashes without even opening. Asks me to clear the cache and try again. I tried to change the sdk versions in build.gradle to match my phone. Still doesn't launch. Flutter is up to date. (APK is not signed)

did you test with the release build or just the debug?
if no, please run flutter build apk to export the apk and try installing

i tried with both flutter build apk and flutter build apk --split-per-abi

Please connect your device and try running flutter run --release command and check. You can also use this with verbose=flag on to check for any issues.
could you please check these two?
